# libc++ for MinGW

Tags: mingw, cross-compiling

ALL,

I am a long time user of MSVC, so please bear with me.

I installed Debian on one of my VMs, then installed `wine64`, `x86_64-w64-mingw32` and `git`. I did it because one of my PR failed for cross-compiling on *nix for Windows.

I cloned the project from git, changed to my PR branch, successfully build it and then build the tests.

However when I tried to run the tests I got an error that the libc++ is missing.

What package I need to install in order to have `libc++`? Is it inside `glibc`? Something else?

If I do just `apt-get install <glibc>` will it install the package for MinGW or for the native Debian gcc version?

Working with MinGW is very new to me, but I'm familiar with Linux/OSX somewhat...

TIA!

EDIT:

This is the result of running:

```
find . -name libstdc++*
```

from / directory:

```
./usr/share/doc/libstdc++6
./usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.29-gdb.py
./usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.29-gdb.py
./usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10-posix/libstdc++.dll.a
./usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10-posix/libstdc++.dll.a-gdb.py
./usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10-posix/libstdc++fs.a
./usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10-posix/libstdc++.a
./usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10-posix/libstdc++-6.dll
./usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10-win32/libstdc++.dll.a
./usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10-win32/libstdc++.dll.a-gdb.py
./usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10-win32/libstdc++fs.a
./usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10-win32/libstdc++.a
./usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10-win32/libstdc++-6.dll
./usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.29
./usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.29
./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
./var/cache/apt/archives/libstdc++6_11.2.0-8_i386.deb
./var/lib/dpkg/info/libstdc++6:i386.prerm
./var/lib/dpkg/info/libstdc++6:amd64.symbols
./var/lib/dpkg/info/libstdc++6:amd64.prerm
./var/lib/dpkg/info/libstdc++6:amd64.triggers
./var/lib/dpkg/info/libstdc++6:i386.list
./var/lib/dpkg/info/libstdc++6:i386.symbols
./var/lib/dpkg/info/libstdc++6:i386.triggers
./var/lib/dpkg/info/libstdc++6:i386.shlibs
./var/lib/dpkg/info/libstdc++6:amd64.md5sums
./var/lib/dpkg/info/libstdc++6:amd64.list
./var/lib/dpkg/info/libstdc++6:i386.md5sums
./var/lib/dpkg/info/libstdc++6:amd64.shlibs
```

As you can see there is no libstdc++-6.dll file available.

And here is the result of `echo ${winepath}`

```
Z:\usr\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\10-win32\libgcc.a;Z:\home\igor\wxWidgets\buildMSW\lib
```

/EDIT

Comment: glibc is not for Windows, MinGW provides the alternative. can you share the command that fails and the returned error?

Comment: @BrechtSanders, command is `wine64 ./test_gui`. the error is `0009:err:module:import_dll Library libgcc_s_seh-1.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\igor\\wxWidgets\\buildMSW\\tests\\test_gui.exe") not found`.

Comment: And another one - `0009:err:module:import_dll Library libstdc++-6.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\igor\\wxWidgets\\buildMSW\\tests\\test_gui.exe") not found`

Comment: You're running the .exe file with wine, but in that environment the location of `libgcc_s_seh-1.dll` and `libstdc++-6.dll` is not in the `PATH`. Try to build with `--static` or copy the required .dll files in the same folder as the .exe and try again.

Comment: @BrechtSanders, what packages are those 2 libraries in? I rebuilt everything to link statically and still have that error. Also,, please see my edit..

Comment: These are part of MinGW/GCC. Use `-static-libgcc` and `-static-libstdc++` to use their static libraries.

Comment: @BrechtSanders, you mean when running `configure`? As said - MinGW, especially on *nix is very new to me...

Comment: @BrechtSanders, also, I'm just curious - how come the GitHuib VMs doesdn't have this problem?

Comment: @BrechtSanders, I tried those and unfortunately both of them are not recognized by configure.

Comment: They are link flags. Add `LDFLAGS="-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++"` to configure. CI builds just build, your issue is not building per se but rather trying to run it on Windows or Wine... Again, running with the right PATH environment variable should solve this. Also check out https://winlibs.com/ to build with MinGW native on Windows instead of cross compiling.

Comment: @BrechtSanders, the GitHub is building and running the test (both). And when I look at the `yml` file I didn't see those options. But if I will be able to run my test - that would be fine. The yml file defines as environment Debian Sid with x86_64-w64-mingw32, wine64 and xvfb installed. And so as in the yml file I'm trying to run `win64 ./test.exe`

Comment: Again, your issue is not building, but running. You should learn more about cross-compilation.